# "Annual Total Records" versus "Total Annual Records"?

Tags: count

I am working on a project for my job, and would like to make sure my grammar is appropriate. There is a chart with the number of records for three consecutive years.

It might seem silly, but I would love some feedback on Which is the best wording for the header?

- Annual Total Records
- Total Annual Records
- Number of Total Records
- Number of Annual Records
- Number of Total Records Annually

Thank you in advance.

Madeline

Comment: Why the -1?  I would think the demoter should post a comment explaining why they think this question is useless.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, realize that you will describe a chart which shows totals by year.  Therefore, the base description should be "Totals".  And, because the chart shows these totals year by year, the qualifier for the base description should be something like "Annual".

I would say the title should be "Annual Totals" or "Totals by Year".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're counting. If you're counting something called a "Total Record", then it would be reasonable to say "Count of 'Total Records'".

Without more context, I can't help you.